# Routing JS and CSS files in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In my MVC code I have areas setup and in each area if there is page specific javascript and css thats where I put my .js and .css files so they are easier to manage. In my web.config for each area I have this

```
<add name="JavaScriptHandler" path="*.js" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
<add name="CSSHandler" path="*.css" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" />
```

Now my actual question. For example lets say my area is called Test, so my folder structure to where my .js file is areas/test/views/test/test.js and if i go to

```
mysite.com/areas/test/views/test/test.js
```

it will show the content of my javascript file yet if i want to go to the actual page itself I just have to type in

```
mysite.com/test/test/edit (the area is test and the controller is test)
```

Is there a way to route my javascript files so I can go to

```
mysite.com/test/test/test.js
```

and get the same results as typing the whole folder structure out? (/areas/test/views etc..)

Comment: mysite.com/test/test/edit makes sense, but mysite.com/test/test/test.js doesn't. A controller doesn't and shouldn't care about js files. You will be hacking the controller look for *.js extension, and serve statically.

Comment: @prakharsingh95 I know that it might not make the most sense but I was just looking for a cleaner url. but is it not possible to do what I'm trying to accomplish?